# почему это так работает, в общем нужно вернуть средний символ из строки, если размер строки четный то 2 средних символа, если нечетный то один

Tags: c++, строки

```
    std::string get_middle(std::string input)
   {
    int size = input.size();
    int index = size / 2;`введите сюда код`
    std::string str = "";
    if (size % 2 == 0)
        str = input[index-1] + input[index]; // вот здесь ломается, выдает ненужный символ
    else
        str = input[index];
    return str;
   } // вот так не работает, хочу понять собственно почему, должна же работать конкатенация строк.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что здесь вы просто складываете два числа, а потом присваиваете их строке:

```
    str = input[index-1] + input[index];
```

Вот так правильнее:

```
if (size % 2 == 0)
    (str += input[index-1]) += input[index];
else
    str += input[index];
```

Только надо предусмотреть защиту для пустой строки...

Но я бы делал так:

```
std::string get_middle(const std::string& input)
{
    if (int size = input.size(); size == 0) return "";
    else return input.substr((size-1)/2,2-size%2);
}
```

Comment: О, ваш минусатор уже с утра в строю ))